# Why Isn't Google Apps Email Address Receiving Email From Magento Website?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, google-apps

Ok, I've been working with this Magento 1.7.0.2 website:

http://www.kharmakhare.com

There are two forms currently on the website. If I change either form to any kharmakhare.com email address, the email is never received. If I change either form to my email address, I get the email just fine.

Yes, I HAVE checked spam. The Kharma Khare email address will not receive emails from Magento. I thought it had to do with the Google Apps not being installed correctly... except when I logged into the email there were already tons of emails in there.

They don't have any problem receiving emails, they just don't receive any emails from the website. I've searched online for an answer. All I can find is problems sending emails through Google Apps, not receiving them.

My client already did set up the SPF records as well. In addition, last time I was in Google Apps (at least a year ago) it looked completely different, so I don't know where anything is anymore.

The first form is on the contact page (this uses Magento's default contact module):

http://www.kharmakhare.com/contact-us

The other is opened by clicking on the "Free Sample" tab on the upper right side of the screen. After spending hours working on this over a couple days I finally figured out how to do what would've been a 10-minute job in wordpress; creating an alternate email form. -_-

Regardless, although I know both forms work, neither one will send to the email address it actually needs to get sent to, and its driving me nuts. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch off the mailserver for that domain.

The reason they are not getting the emails and you are is that the sending address is `something@kharmakhare.com` and the receiving address is `somethingelse@kharmakhare.com`.  The MX records offloading the email to Google Apps are not used in this instance as the server will look for the local mailserver first.

Comment: After checking online how to do this for the server in question, I know now that it works successfully. Thanks a lot; I'd have never figured it out on my own.

Comment: Excellent! No problem at all :)

Comment: @JaidynReiman, do you have any idea where you obtained instructions to do this? I'm having a similar issue and can't find a way to do this.

Comment: @MxmastaMills - It depends on your system.  I do it from inside Plesk as my VPS ran Plesk but you can do it from CPanel and the others.  And of course directly on the server if you can work with SSH on the server.