# Mails not being delivered due to local-host-names

Tags: magento, email, vps, webmin

I am having some trouble delivering mail messages sent by the Magento contact form. Mails to 'local' mail addresses are not being delivered, however mails to other addresses áre being delivered.

I am using a unmanaged VPS with Webmin panel, but the mailaddresses have been set up in the hosting panel (so, outside the VPS).

Could someone help me out with this?
I don't know that mach about this subject.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This comes up very now and again and has nothing to do with Magento;

[Why Isn't Google Apps Email Address Receiving Email From Magento Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036413/why-isnt-google-apps-email-address-receiving-email-from-magento-website/15038847#15038847)

It's normally to do with the mailserver being left turned on in your VPS even though your MX are being handled elsewhere.  Turn off the mailserver in the panel.

Comment: Hi, I just pressed the 'Stop Postfix'-button in my Webmin-panel. I guess this turns off the mailserver, right?
Mails are still not being delivered, but will be stored in the Postfix 'Mail Queue'. After starting again, mails are being delivered to external mail addresses. Internal mails won't be delivered.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used webmin so I have no idea what setting turns off your local mailserver I'm afraid. Don't know if you saw this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/16962/how-to-remove-the-sendmail-mail-server-from-webmin