# Magento emails are not working

Tags: magento, webmail

All Emails in magento are not sending to webmail account, we are using gmail account they are sending, but webmail account they are not sending. is there any restriction to webmail accounts to magento?

Comment: I am guessing that the webmail account is for the same domain as the magento site, right?

Comment: The reason I ask - make sure this isn't your issue -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036413/why-isnt-google-apps-email-address-receiving-email-from-magento-website/15038847#15038847